repomd.xml parser error when trying to install from a yum offline repo
I'm currently working on a RedHat 8.5 based environment that's completely isolated from the internet and from the LAN.
Given the need of installing packages into a new machine I proceeded to mount an official RHEL 8.5 ISO to the /mnt/cdrom/ folder and then I created this new redhat.repo file inside the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory:
[InstallMedia-AppStream]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 - AppStream
metadata_expire=-1
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/AppStream/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[InstallMedia-BaseOs]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 - BaseOs
metadata_expire=-1
gpgcheck=0
cost=500
enabled=1
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom/BaseOS/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

The AppStream repo gets correctly picked up and I managed to succesfully install some packages from it but when I try to, let's say, run a yum update I get this error:
[user@host yum.repos.d]# yum update
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 - BaseOs                                                2.7 MB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'InstallMedia-BaseOs': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 1 (Document is empty
)


I also noticed that the repomd.xml file inside the BaseOS folder is completely unreadable, being displayed as a file full of ideograms from a text editor, as if it was a binary file, while the one belonging to AppStream it is a regular and fully human-readable XML file.
Furthermore, trying to manually install with a rpm -i any of the packages contained inside the BaseOS folder gives an error like this:
not an rpm package (or package manifest)
this has only further exacerbated my confusion.
Thanks for your help.

I did read somewhere that offline machines, that are STIG'd, are having this issue due to a gpgcheck entry in the yum.conf.  I haven't found an answer that I'm satisfied with because my machines have to remain STIG'd.

In the end the .iso image that I have been provided was busted.
Downloading a new one from Red Hat's website solved the problem.
I could've realized it earlier, I suppose, but seeing the AppStream folder and it's content being recognized put me on the wrong track.
Thanks for your answer anyway, much appreciated.
